# Upload multiple files in PHP with Queue

Tags: php, file-upload

I'm facing problem in building api for uploading multiple files. 
I've divide multiple file upload into single upload for each file ( api call per file ). But How to connect all files.

**Post Table: ( id, caption )**

**PostAttachment : ( id, post_id, image )**

Scenario : Uploading 20 photos with caption "SOME_TEXT". For the first file Post will be added with one PostAttachment and for later files PostAttachment will be append with previous post_id.

Comment: Any code? What have you done already?

Comment: I just need help in flow/architecture

Comment: Could you revision the question? The problem is not clear (at least to me).